# How to connect/use a saved query in a new SQL query in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a saved query in BigQuery. Now I open a new SQL editor and write new SQL query that needs this saved query as temporary table for computing. Is it possible to do it that way?I am using new Google Cloud version and there is only one "saved queries" menu on the bottom. It seems all queries are stored here.

Comment: Save that query as a view, then you can use the view in subsequent queries.

Answer (score 2):

The recommended way to do this, is as the comment above suggested, save it as a view:

```
CREATE VIEW `project_id.dataset.view_name` AS
( SELECT id, field_name FROM `project_id.dataset.table_name` where id = 1 );
```

This way you will be able to see the view and the schema in the BQ menu, below your corresponding dataset. To get info, or reference from that view then you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM `project_id.dataset.view_name`
```

Remember that as this is a view, each time that you reference the view essentially you will be running the query, so it will consume resources.